# I can't make simple playlists with music I purchases ever since I activated apple music. How do I fix this?

Tags: itunes

I can't make playlists with any music I bought after activating apple music. I've been trying to make a playlist to burn the new Lamb of Gad album without success so I can listen to it in my car. I bought the album on iTunes. I've been trying for two days now.

When I try to drag a song into the playlist I get "iCloud Music Library Playlists can only contain songs from your iCloud music library.’
If you continue Lamb of God will only be available on this computer.”
A button says remove playlist and continue.".

That sounds like what I want but that's not what happens. If I click the button I only have 3 of 12 songs that will actually copy to the playlist and I have no idea how I even made that possible. There used to be a cloud icon I could click to download my purchases directly onto my hard drive (which is what I prefer because I want my hard drive to take priority over the cloud.). There is no such icon. I can't differentiate what tracks are in iCloud and what are on my computer.