# Access music from old iTunes account

Tags: itunes

I changed my Apple ID for the 3rd time because my password keeps getting changed. How can I access my iTunes music from the first two Apple IDs?

Comment: Missing a lot of information here. Do you know the Apple IDs? Do you know the passwords? Just a few starting questions. If you know both check out.
http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/

Comment: you better look into why "password keeps getting changed"... what things come to mind when you think, why is this happening... do you have lots of cracked programs, strange browser plugins, or passwords commonly used for other accounts?

Answer (score 1):

The very easiest way, which it sounds like you need!, would be to [burn CDs](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19494?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) of your old songs, by signing in to each account, by making a [playlist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208391/i-cant-make-simple-playlists-with-music-i-purchases-ever-since-i-activated-appl) and then selecting, **burn playlist to disk.**

To access the music from your first two Apple IDs you just need the user name and password from each one.  Reset your password so that you know the current password for each... make it something random and long that you just write on a piece of paper, and throw away after you re-import the songs into your current account.